# How to read or store integers, by reading line by line in C?

Tags: c, io, stdin

I'm trying to read line of numbers and do some calculations on them. However, I need to them to be separated line by line somehow, but I can't figure out how to do that. Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    int infor[1024]; //2-d array perhaps??
    int n, i;

    i=0;

    int imgWidth, imgHeight, safeRegionStart, safeRegionWidth;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = stdin;

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &infor[i++]);
    }
}
```

---

The input looks something like this:

```
4 3 1 2 -16777216 -16711936 -65536 -16777216 -1 -65536 -65536 -16711936 -16777216 -65536 -16711936 -16777216     
3 4 1 1 -16777216 -16711936 -1 -1 -65536 -16777216 -16777216 -65536 -1 -1 -65536 -16711936
```

Can anyone explain how to move from line to line?

---

**EDIT:**

```
int main()
{
    FILE * fp = stdin;
    char buffer[1024];
    long arr[2][16];

    int i = 0,
        j = 0;

    char * pEnd;

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
    {
        j = 0;
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
            continue;

        pEnd = buffer;
        while(*pEnd != '\0')
        {
            arr[i][j++]=strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,10);
        }

        i++;
    }

    int imgWidth,
        imgHeight,
        safeRegionStart,
        safeRegionWidth;

    imgWidth = arr[1][0];
    imgHeight = arr[1][1];
    safeRegionStart = arr[1][2];
    safeRegionWidth = arr[1][3];

    printf("Value of i is %d\n", i);
    printf("%d %d %d %d ",
           imgWidth,
           imgHeight,
           safeRegionStart,
           safeRegionWidth);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user373466 Having it as `stdin` does make a difference since you have to input those values by hand (or by redirecting input, I suppose).

Comment: @user373466 If you are entering them by hand, you need to enter all of the numbers in the top row on one line separated by a space, then hit enter. You can't hit enter after each one unless you take the input by different means.

Comment: I am not entering them manually. I am trying to read from the command line (Stdin), since I won't be given the file name...

Comment: @user373466 How are the values being redirected in?  Perhaps knowing more about the process will help to figure out the best way.  As it stands, with the code I gave you, it's mean to read from a file formatted in the way that you indicated.

Comment: I am simply doing it via command line redirection i.e. a.exe < image.dat, where image.dat contains the data of all those numbers line by line.i.e. Line1 - 4 3 1 2 -16777216..... Line2 - 3 4 1 1 -16777216.... Sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: However, I will not know what the filename is, that is why fopen is not working...

Comment: Okay.  I got rid of `fopen` and put the parameter `stdin` directly into the `fgets` statement as `while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)` and entered
`rowdata2 < rowdata.txt`
and got `arr[1][0]=3 / arr[1][1]=4 / arr[1][2]=1`

Comment: @user373466 I didn't see that you eliminated the space in between the lines (sorry, I guess you alluded to it in your comment).  If so, you can eliminate the `if(buffer[0]=='\n') continue;` portion, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Can you make changes to your code block below. I don't get why or where you did rowdata2 < rowdata.txt

Comment: I'm still getting 0 values, after I changed fp to stdin. Did you change anything else?

Comment: @user373466 That was just the executable name.  I was redirecting the file that I made of the data into it at the prompt.

Comment: @user373466 No, I didn't change anything else.  I just removed the empty line in between the lines of data and it still works, even with the if statement in there.

Comment: That is really bizarre. How are you printing them out? 
printf("%d %d %d", arr[1][0], arr[1][1], arr[1][2]);

Comment: @user373466 `printf("arr[1][0]=%d / arr[1][1]=%d / arr[1][2]=%d\n",arr[1][0],arr[1][1],arr[1][2]);`  If you have a debugger, you should step through your program and see where the values are getting lost.  You could also print out the value right after the `strtol`.  The only thing I can think of that might be helpful is putting `%ld` for the specifier in `printf` since the numbers are longs.

Comment: @user373466 Did you find the bug?

Comment: Yes, I did. I added fclose(fp) where FILE *fp = stdin; Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user373466 Glad it worked.  If you put a check for `j<16` in the while loop it should be okay.  I think that `strtol` was choking on the extra spaces and kept looking for more numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your 2D array idea is probably correct, especially if you want to keep the data points separate.  Use `fgets` to bring in each line as a string, then use a loop with `sscanf` to parse out the individual numbers into a single row of the array.  A function like `strtol` can be used in place of the `sscanf` step to get the numbers directly.

For example* (you'll need to adjust the size of the buffer and the dimensions of the array, but for the data file you gave):
(edits made for the stdin approach)

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char buffer[1024];
    long arr[2][16];
    int i = 0,j=0;
    char * pEnd;
    FILE *fp = stdin;
    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp))
    {
        j=0;
        if(buffer[0]=='\n')
            continue;

        pEnd = buffer;
        while(*pEnd !='\0')
        {
            arr[i][j++]=strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,10);

        }

        i++;
    }

fclose(fp);
printf("arr[0][0]=%d  arr[0][1]=%d  arr[0][2]=%d\n",arr[0][0],arr[0][1],arr[0][2]);
printf("arr[1][0]=%d  arr[1][1]=%d  arr[1][2]=%d\n",arr[1][0],arr[1][1],arr[1][2]);


}
```

The exe is named `rowdata2` and the text file is `rowdata.txt`, so I ran it as `rowdata2 < rowdata.txt` and got the correct results.

[*] It won't win any beauty contests

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for outputting correct values when I do arr[1][0], arr[1][1], arr[1][2] only works for arr[0][n]. Any reason why?

Comment: If I output the values I get `arr[1][0]=3 / arr[1][1]=4 / arr[1][2]=1`.  What are the values that you are getting?  If you want, post the current code as an addendum to your question.

Comment: Well, Im getting 0, 0, 0,. The only thing is I have *fp equal to stdin, instead of explicitly giving it a filename, I am not sure if that makes a difference.